# Delete migrated questions

Tags: support, migration

The migrated questions are shown as locked by Community and it is closed. Why these questions not deleted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some questions, especially the FAQ ones, have been linked to from many places, and deleting the question completely would break that link. Perhaps a simple redirect from the old link to the new location of the question would be a good compromise?

Comment: Also, many people have favorited the questions that were moved.

Comment: Good point. If they aren't already, favorites should (when possible) be moved over with the question. Maybe if a user that's marked a question as a favorite doesn't have an account on the target site the link in their favorites tab on the old site points to the question's new home on the new site?

Comment: Yeah... Again, a redirect would solve the problem. Gotta love HTTP...