# Please have "Community User" take ownership of questions when they are migrated

Tags: support, status-completed, migration

Every time I look at my profile page on Stack Overflow, I am reminded of two "meta" questions I asked before Meta Stack Overflow existed.

These questions have nothing to do with programming and I see no reason to be advertising them on Stack Overflow anymore.

When content is migrated to a new site, can the community user take ownership of the question on the original site, so it is no longer tied to me on the original site?

It's cluttering up my profile page.

(Note: Jon Skeet is also affected by this.)

Comment: Another solution would be to allow the asker to delete the stub: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/allow-asker-to-delete-migrated-question

Comment: @Kyle, I think the advantage of this solution is that it has no negative impact (Eg. broken links) and sounds fairly cheap to implement.

Comment: @Sam: Well the one downside is that an asker might not be aware that their question is migrated, so immediately rescinding ownership is a bad idea. This might work if the OP could intentionally disown their questions.

Comment: Deleting the stubs would also have the added benefit of clearing out the (misleading) hits from Google.

Comment: @Kyle, perhaps have a delay then - have community user take ownership after 14 days ...

Comment: Also send a message/event to the user notifying them of the migration, and include the link to the new location.

Answer (score 3):

Flag them for moderator attention indicating what you want done with them (deletion).

Edit: marking this completed as [you can flag locked posts now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/ability-to-flag-locked-posts).

Comment: It's not possible to flag locked posts

Comment: Atwood I think Flags should expire. I flagged this question for migration a long time ago, and now I can't flag it again to have it deleted from Stack Overflow proper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357167/what-is-the-origin-of-your-so-username-closed

Comment: @George, flags do expire.  The issue is that you only get one per post per lifetime; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46472/why-can-you-only-flag-a-given-post-for-mod-attention-once)

Comment: Flags are no longer limited to one per lifetime: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/once-a-flag-is-cleared-from-the-mod-queue-the-same-post-cannot-be-re-flagged