# Ability to flag locked posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderators, locked

When you lock a post, you also lock out users from being able to flag for moderator attention on said post.

It would be a useful feature to allow flagging from the post if something has changed or needs to be changed with the locking of the post. It would allow a user to explain their reasoning within the relevance of the post/page itself.

I found out [due to a question](https://superuser.com/questions/67128/notepad-load-langs-xml-failed-closed) that needed to be locked/closed due to some answer spam issues. It was a legit question and I did not want the OP to feel like he had done anything wrong.

I posted a comment explaining why I did this and wanted users to be able to flag the question if something legitimate needed to be added. That is when I noticed that you can't flag the question after being locked.

Nothing major, just an idea.

Comment: Just today I saw one with an accepted answer that amounted to a broken link. I don't know what the moderator would've done, but I couldn't do anything.

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes yes **YES.**

Comment: For historical lock the request is not complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locked posts can now be flagged for moderator attention.

However, if a question is [locked for historical significance](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), then no option for flagging is currently available.

Comment: I can't see how to flag this answer where the (popular) question is locked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/323559/992887 - no Flag option.  The Gitmac/Sprout website link currently redirects to a porn site, maybe a moderator could look at this since I can't flag it?

Comment: I'll check into it, but for now, I've fixed the link.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Has this since been reverted? I can't find any option to flag when posts are locked.

Comment: @StevenJeuris which post?  If the parent question is [locked for historical significance](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), then no flagging option is currently available.

Comment: How do we flag questions locked for historical significance?

Answer (score 1):

I would be all for this.

However -- assuming I understand this part of SO right -- flagging is a type of voting, and you can't vote on a locked post. There is an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/give-diamond-moderators-the-ability-to-partially-lock-a-post) to allow partial locking (in that case, only forbid closing and deletion votes); in other words, to allow specifying the allowed and restricted types of voting.

I'll vote to close this question as a dupe, just wanted to explain this.

And I repeat: I'm all for doing this. Until then, the workaround is to flag a different post and mention "This is about Q 67128: …" in the message.

Comment: Voting to partial-lock could be a good ability to open up to 5k+ or 7k+ users, maybe?

Comment: @Æther: Hmm, I don't know, I think I'd leave that in the hands of the mods.

Comment: this sounds like the `flag` function is poorly defined or poorly implemented (or both).  i can see why you should only flag a post as offensive or spam once, but i honestly can't see why "flag for moderator attention" should be a once-only ability.