# Unable To Flag A Response on a Locked Post. Feature or Bug?

Tags: support, flags, locked-questions, historical-lock

According to [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37130/142865), which is now [status-completed], it should be possible for me to be able to flag a [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530477/241536) to a [locked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/241536), but I can't.

I have plenty of rep on SO.  Is the fact that I can't flag an answer on a locked post there a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 9):

It's not an ordinary lock. The question in question has a *historical lock*, no actions are available on such questions.

Comment: See also: [What is a historical lock and what is it used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)