# How to flag community wiki posts?

Tags: support, flags, historical-lock

I came across the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312426/1275169

This is effectively a link-only answer and the link is broken now. I usually flag such posts. But strangely enough, there's no *flag* option. I thought of commenting  with *Broken link*. But that option is also not available.

Is this because it's a community wiki? Why there's no option to flag even if it's one? On a general case, how do we address case provided I can't flag/comment on that. Bringing a meta post every such instance is not really user-friendly. Shouldn't there a better alternative?

Comment: It's historically locked.

Comment: And with respect to that lock, this answers says it all: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40127/161198 *"if a question is locked for historical significance, then no option for flagging is currently available."*

Comment: @Mysticial Shouldn't a broken link be fixed in the *history* then ;-) ? I guess the point of moderator deleting posts is to remove useless info from the site. That's answer is not useful anymore.

Comment: @KingsIndian I don't have an opinion on this. But a similar case has happened before and casperOne basically said to leave it for dead.

Comment: @Mysticial That's always an option for *anything* on SO In guess ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/other will do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That whole question is locked:

> ## locked by [Robert Harvey♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) Oct 5 '11 at 5:45

This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

None of the answers on that page have flag links, anything [locked for historical significance](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) [cannot be flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/ability-to-flag-locked-posts/40127#40127).

*Normally* you can flag wiki posts just fine (such as this [famous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)).

Comment: Since the link is broken, it has no *significance* ;)

Comment: @KingsIndian: perhaps not; but the page itself has historical significance, so it is locked in stasis.

Comment: @KingsIndian: That particular page was preserved at https://www.evernote.com/shard/s9/note/a59f48fe-3569-4c31-b08d-0f98823f4cc7/wishi/crazylazy

Comment: I am not questioning the whole page but only that post. But why system is not addressing something that's no longer useful.

Comment: @KingsIndian: The page at some point in time was useful, but SO has decided to no longer maintain such posts. It is frozen forever, no point in fixing links.

Comment: If it wasn't locked, the whole question would likely be deleted. This *is* the compromise for handling the situation - keep it the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by MartijnPieters, the question is locked and thus cannot be touched in any way by non-moderators.

However, since link rot sucks I've edited that answer to point to the Wayback Machine's archived version of the linked page.

Comment: Let's hope archive.org never goes away.

Comment: Good that you linked it :)