# Description of single item is weird when flagging the own post

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface, wording, original-poster

When I flag a post where I'm the original poster I see the following popup where only one item can be selected:

> [image: above]

There are no items above (and below too), and I’m not sure that current wording is correct in such cases.

Comment: This also happens on locked posts. And I think also deleted posts.

Comment: @Laurel there is no “flag” link on locked post. Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) for example. But you’re right about deleted posts.

Comment: Posts locked for things other than historical significance [can be flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40127/323179). And it looks like this doesn’t apply to the (iOS) app, since I seem to be able to flag even historically significant posts.