# Should question stubs left over from migration be deleted?

Tags: discussion, migration

There are thousands of stub questions on Stack Overflow that are left over after a migration to SU or SF.  I know they serve a good purpose, but it seems like a rather short-term purpose to me.  Should we be deleting these after a few days, or is there a reason to keep them around long-term?

One reason I ask is that I'd like to rid Stack Overflow of the `not-programming-related` tag, but *a lot* of the questions with that tag are migration stubs.  If I just remove the tag it would spam the Active tab with a bunch of closed stubs.  *Not* preferred.  (Just removing the tag isn't my goal to begin with.  I'd like to remove the questions that make the tag seem necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these migration stubs need to be actively deleted now to trigger the [automatic redirects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mov).

Comment: It might be worth to automate this, since there are a lot of these migrations (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/delete-old-migrated-questions)

Answer (score 2):

I brought this up a while back when I was working on moving my meta questions over here, and I wanted the [ability to delete the question stubs from my Stack Overflow profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/allow-asker-to-delete-migrated-question). I understand leaving the migrated question short-term so that the asker knows where the question went, but I don't see any compelling reason for the stub to continue to exist, especially when the asker themselves wants the question removed.

This has since been mitigated somewhat by allowing users to flag their own posts for moderator attention, but it's still a very manual process. I think that it would be best to purge the stub after, say, a week after the question was migrated.