# Delete old migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

There are thousands of old questions on SO that got migrated a long time ago and don't add any value to the site. These questions should be deleted. Due to the [recently added redirects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mov/52585#52585) of deleted migrated questions, users following old links would even be redirected to the new home of the question.

The easiest way to handle this would be an automated task. Some period of time after the migration (like a month or two weeks), the migrated question should automatically be removed.

Comment: ... unless it is upvoted, answered or the owner has also signed up at the migrated-to-site, perhaps?

Comment: @Tobias: Any answers are migrated with the question and then deleted on the source site. Only the question itself remains after a migration, as a pointer to the migrated thread. It also gets locked on migration, so no further answers, votes or comments can be posted. You basically can't do anything with remaining stub besides following the "migrated to" link.

Comment: Related: [Should question stubs left over from migration be deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46954/should-question-stubs-left-over-from-migration-be-deleted)  I didn't bring up the proposal of automating the deletions though, so this is a unique question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your request as deleting orphaned questions on the migration-destiny, not the remainder on the origin

Answer (score 3):

The stubs are now [lopped off after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082) on the original site.

A user tripping over them should be automatically redirected to the new host of the question.