# Can a migrated question be deleted without harming the new question on another site?

Tags: support, migration, deleted-questions, migrated-questions

Can a migrated question be removed without any harm for the new message in another forum? Does it serve as a link only or is there a deeper connection between the original and the migrated question? I just would like to remove the link and want to know if it is safe.

Comment: Are you talking about migrated ***questions***? If so, then yes, you can delete stubs for questions that have been migrated to other sites. They're just there as a convenience redirection for the asker and anyone else who might not know the question has been migrated to another site.

Comment: Yep. That was what I wanted to know. Make an answer and I'll accept. I also modified that I talk about ***questions***

Comment: Actually not. I cannot delete the link, because the redirect is immediate and I cannot see any menu on main page to remove it.

Comment: Are you a moderator on the site? I'm not sure if regular users have the ability to delete these. You can click on the link in the "migrated from" text, though, and return to the original question stub on the original site. You might be able to delete it from there.

Comment: Had to make that via flag because I did not have rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the stubs for questions that have been migrated to other sites. They're just there as a convenience redirection for the asker and anyone else who might not know the question has been migrated to another site.

Also see: [Should question stubs left over from migration be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46954/should-question-stubs-left-over-from-migration-be-deleted)

Comment: Are they not auto-deleted after some time?