# Why does a site-migrated question leave the old question and old downvoted score trailing around?

Tags: support, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow asker to delete migrated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/allow-asker-to-delete-migrated-question)

My question has been migrated to another site. Because it wasn't the right fit for the first site - it got downvoted. If the question gets migrated, why is the old question with the old score still hanging around like a bad smell on the first site?

What can I do about it?

Comment: The reason it leaves the old question is to serve as a "pointer" to the question on the new site. The question "stubs" on the original site are [automatically deleted after 30 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082). You can delete them yourself before then, if you so choose. No harm will come in doing so.