# Broken link in Linked Posts section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-questions

I'm trying out this new feature and I noticed in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome

One of the links in the Linked section is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Which gives a page-not-found.

Maybe that page was moved here.. i dunno. But the link shouldn't be broken.

Answer (score 6):

Technically it isn't *broken*, as the page still exists.

The only caveat is that you have to have over 10k rep points to see it.

I vouch for those links to be kept, may be only shown to the people that can see the content.

Comment: What's the point of showing me a link to something I cannot see? I can't even tell if it's because I don't have enough rep or because it's simply non-existent...

Comment: If only I could upvote a comment multiple times...

Comment: It's more tricky than that. The post does exist, but has been moved here on meta, and the system knows that.. It could simply send a permanent redirect to here instead of the 404.

Comment: @Kop / @Assaf - yup, see my respective long standing [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17552/45773), which fortunately has now been [implemented as of June 04/2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17552#52585). Given this the bug at hand should have been tagged `status-completed` as well, but unfortunately the Stack Exchange team doesn't really appear to maintain their issue queues ...

Answer (score 2):

Linked questions are cleaned up every 30 days, and also any time anything in the question is edited; so just be patient and these deleted linked items will be removed over time.

Comment: should linked questions also be cleaned up if they still exist, but were mentioned in deleted comments? If yes, then you might want to have a look at [Questions not removed from “Linked” when comments are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/questions-not-removed-from-linked-when-comments-are-deleted), which shows linked questions from comments that were deleted Friday January 14th (about 35 days ago today).