# Questions not removed from "Linked" when comments are deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

This has been reported a long time ago; things might very well have been fixed by now. I can hardly imagine this is a real issue, but *maybe* it's not too nice for SEO or the data dump? So:

[A question](https://superuser.com/questions/232813/what-goes-on-when-requesting-a-url-in-a-browser) on Super User had its comments about duplicates removed by a moderator. However, the "Linked" section still showed the links *for many months*, until somebody edited an answer:

[image: Linked section still shows the deleted references]

[Jeff writes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47898/broken-link-in-linked-posts-section/79318#79318) that links are cleaned up every 30 days, or whenever a post is edited. The first was not true for this example: the links were definitely still there almost 4 months later (on May 4th 2011). Looking again in October showed the links were okay, but at that time the post had been edited.

I think [one link](https://superuser.com/questions/182800/explain-how-the-internet-works-to-a-complete-computer-novice) was still used in the 4 close votes that had not expired yet. [The other](https://superuser.com/questions/157408/what-happens-when-you-enter-a-url-in-your-browser) was a link to another duplicate, which might only have been in the comments, not in any vote. (As I voted, I only see "You have already voted to close this question" so cannot validate which duplicates were used. Both links were in my comments.)

This is related to [Posts linked in deleted answers still show up under “Linked”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64743/posts-linked-in-deleted-answers-still-show-up-under-linked), which meanwhile has been tagged `status-bydesign`. But while 10k can see deleted answers, deleted *comments* cannot been seen by anyone but moderatos.

Comment: (Just for the record: the comments were deleted over a week ago now, no changes. So *if* some daily script is supposed to fix this, then something is wrong.)

Comment: Still linked [today](http://i.imgur.com/yXei1.png), since January 14th. But [apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47898/broken-link-in-linked-posts-section/79318#79318) they are cleaned up every 30 days, or whenever a post is edited. So, hopefully nobody edits — and we should see the links disappear soon now!

Comment: Note that the linked questions, [Explain how the Internet works to a complete computer novice](http://superuser.com/questions/182800/explain-how-the-internet-works-to-a-complete-computer-novice) and [What happens when you enter a URL in your browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/157408/what-happens-when-you-enter-a-url-in-your-browser), do NOT link back to [that question](http://superuser.com/questions/232813/what-goes-on-when-requesting-a-url-in-a-browser) that still shows these two links. (Still linked.)

Comment: (Still linked; still no edits. Another example [here on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87284/how-about-linking-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-message-to-faq), linking to [a FAQ on protected questions](http://i.imgur.com/M2Src.png) in a comment I deleted just today.)

Comment: Just tested in another question: editing an answer does update the "Linked" section and remove obsolete links. I've not touched the examples mentioned above, just in case they can help troubleshooting the background processes. So: still linked today, still no edits.

Comment: Okay, meanwhile an answer on the example from my question was edited, and its "Linked" section is empty now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did this question get a 'linked' question that isn't mentioned in comments or answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110938/how-did-this-question-get-a-linked-question-that-isnt-mentioned-in-comments-o)

Comment: @Flexo, I don't think it's a dupe. True, it's showing the same behavior, but even there Balpha's answer suggests things are resolved by waiting, like I referred to in my 2nd comment too. But that's not true; things were not fixed until someone edited half a year later.

Comment: was about to ask this. so question1 has comment linking to question2, after edit of which question does the link get removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a missing call to our sync code here - it will happen appropriately after the next build.  What happens typically is one of 2 cases:

- If you're *adding* a link, just see if we have that link, add it if not
- If you're removing or changing a link...we have to re-check all links (you can't just remove it, maybe it was referenced many times, etc.)

Removing a comment wasn't triggering either case, now it will appropriately trigger the second.

Comment: Seems like the "Linked" section might still be outdated when comments are auto-deleted, like [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189972/shouldnt-badges-like-beta-and-area-51-be-removed-if-they-can-no-longer-be-award) ([screenshot 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FNL5l.png), and [screenshot 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gRYJm.png) when an additional link was added).

Comment: (The stale link I saw in my previous comment, is now gone. Just leaving the comment here in case you want to investigate.)

Comment: Nick, linking is supposed to be a two-way thing, right? Like if in some post I link to another question, then that other question should show a link back to the first question? If so: that's not working [in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167018/deleted-users-name-shows-on-area-51), to which I had to add a comment to link to [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-prior-to-deletion/167794#167794) that linked there. Deleting my comment also makes the "Linked" section disappear again.