# How about linking "Sorry we are no longer accepting questions ..." message to FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, post-ban, error-message

How about linking the "Sorry we are no longer accepting questions ..." message to the appropriate FAQ question like this?

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. [Learn more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wondering why people are able to find Meta to post their complaint, but then fail to do a simple search before posting their ([often *bad*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-ban)) question here, I suddenly realize that the question block also prevents people from complaining about it on the main sites. So:

Wouldn't linking to the FAQ attract more [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) to Meta?

(Or: do we want to help those who cannot even find the FAQ themselves? I only feel pity for those who get the ban because of shared IP addresses, but I don't know if that has actually happened. Even then: good citizens will then figure out how to find the FAQ?)

Comment: I don't know about vampires theory. Is there any way to find out how many users are now getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?

Comment: And, @YOU, how many IP addresses are involved? I guess there's only [one way to find out](http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) ;-)

Comment: @arjan are you offering? :)

Comment: @Arjan, heh, I have never done LISP programming language, and not sure I could get permanent legal right to work at US, and I don't believe I speak excellent English :P

Comment: New York, nah, @Jeff ;-) (And really, see me hanging around here at MSO, not doing anything at SO... Shame on me!)

Comment: @arjan core team is distributed worldwide

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to Help Vampires @Arjan :-)

Comment: @Rory, it's actually taken from the right column on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).