# How did this question get a 'linked' question that isn't mentioned in comments or answers?

Tags: support, linked-questions, deleted-comments

Looking at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110916/how-can-i-best-use-stackexchange-as-a-qa-site-for-my-own-project which has been closed as a duplicate (quite right), we see **three** 'linked' questions in the sidebar; however, only **two** of those questions are given as duplicate-close-targets. [Use Stack Overflow as the official support site of an open-source project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stackoverflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project) which to my mind is the actual 'exact duplicate', isn't mentioned anywhere else except in the 'linked questions' sidebar itself!

The [blogpost that introduced linked questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/) says:

> The Linked sidebar... gathers up any links to this question provided by the community via comments, answers, or questions

So how did [Use Stack Overflow as the official support site of an open-source project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stackoverflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project) get into the linked questions sidebar of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110916/how-can-i-best-use-stackexchange-as-a-qa-site-for-my-own-project? (There's no explicit link in the other direction, in case you were wondering.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was linked in a now-deleted comment. There can be a delay between the link being removed and the "linked questions" list being updated. You'll noticed that this has happened in the meantime; the link isn't there anymore.

Comment: actually link never get removed [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23194664/821057)

Comment: Can you comment on how long that delay can be? I'm curious about why [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134052/definition-of-a-field-line) is marked as Linked to [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82536/why-does-the-density-of-electric-field-lines-make-sense-if-there-is-a-field-lin); the only thing I can find is [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134052/definition-of-a-field-line#comment274378_134056), which has been deleted for 4+ years.