# Why is this question "linked"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions not removed from “Linked” when comments are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/questions-not-removed-from-linked-when-comments-are-deleted)

Given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647724/utorrent-and-really-slow-internet if we look at the linked questions on the right, we see

[an illustration pointing out the oddity http://i.imm.io/dCgg.png](http://i.imm.io/dCgg.png)

So what gives. Why is this linked? I don't see anything on the other Q that seems to link back to this one, either. [Are there practical uses for dynamic-casting to void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123776/are-there-practical-uses-for-dynamic-casting-to-void-pointer)

Comment: and now the OP is deleted, so this is probably useless except for those over 10k on [so]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was totally my fault. My comment originally linked to the wrong question, which I was answering at the same time. I later edited to fix it when I spotted what I'd done. Looks like the "linked" questions outlived the edit I made though.

Comment: Indeed the linked section [is not updated, until some post is edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/questions-not-removed-from-linked-when-comments-are-deleted).