# Deleted user's name shows on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, deleted-accounts

On the [new Weapons Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50612/weapons-firearms-knives-archery-etc) on Area 51, a deleted user proposed this. His name is still shown for "proposed by", but it should probably not show that...

[image]

In addition his name *is* obscured [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9075/is-it-a-viable-proposal), on a comment. I remembered it was from that user, because I saw that discussion before he was deleted.

> @jmort253 It was a few years ago, SE is much bigger, and it never hurts to try. – user74355 Feb 5 at 23:05

Comment: For some reason not listed in the "Linked" section on the right, so a manual reference just to get it listed: [Further anonymize deleted accounts by changing the username prior to deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-prior-to-deletion).