# Why doesn't this question have any linked questions?

Tags: bug, linked-questions

The question in question: [What rules govern forced removal from flights (due to overbooking)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91409/what-rules-govern-forced-removal-from-flights-due-to-overbooking)

There are two questions linked to in comments, but no linked questions are appearing in the sidebar. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/91409 is also empty.

Also, this post doesn't show up in "linked questions" of the linked questions:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/12905
- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/84495

[image]

Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit), on macOS 10.12.4, in case it is JavaScript messing up.

The comments have been moved to chat once, so could this be due to the relevant comment having been deleted and undeleted?

Another example, from Workplace: [Having lunch at home](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/88091/having-lunch-at-home). The top comment links to [How can I politely decline a team lunch?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-can-i-politely-decline-a-team-lunch), but [linked questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/88091) doesn't include it. This post has also had comments moved to chat, so it's likely the top comment here has been undeleted as well.

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome 57.0.2987.133 on Windows 8.

Comment: Does the same on firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit) on windows 10 Version 1703

Comment: Repro'd on Safari on macOS Sierra. So they're probably not stored in the database.

Comment: Yep, I'm increasingly leaning towards comment (un)deletion being the problem...

Comment: Also, the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/91409/linked?site=travel) doesn't report any linked questions.

Comment: AFAIK, the deleted comment shouldn't remove linked questions in general, but I don't know for chat migration case.

Comment: @Elephant I think that's not the case: [Questions not removed from "Linked" when comments are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/questions-not-removed-from-linked-when-comments-are-deleted)

Comment: Now it has [one linked q](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/91485) listed (because it was marked as a dupe), but the two you mentioned from the comment still aren't listed.

Comment: Perhaps this is because those comments use HTTP links instead of HTTPS?