# Comment links starting with double slashes (//) doesn't show up in linked posts

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, linked-questions

If the below, for example, is posted as a comment, the linked post doesn't show up in Linked in the sidebar.

```
[Doesn't show up in linked.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122)
```

This seems like a bug.

Comment: [Doesn't show up in linked.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122)

Comment: [Why doesn't this question have any linked questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294605) is related, but that appears to have a different cause.