# Linked questions not visible for few questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, linked-questions

I have added a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11603473/6908282) and linked it to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22992543/6908282) since they are related. But when I see the other question, I don't see any "Linked Question" List that typically gets populated towards the right (Screenshot below).

I have created on a browser extension called [Stack Me First](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/StackMeFirst#stackmefirst) which shows a list of linked questions, comments & answers related to the user. And it has been working fine until I got to this question.

Does it take time for the Linked Questions list to be populated in the DOM, when we add a first comment linking to another question?

Screenshot of the question (*note that the screenshot is cropped to reduce the length*):
[image: Screenshot for Stack Overflow question showing that Linked Questions list is not visible]

Comment: As an aside, is it your browser extension that chopped the top of the answer off too? ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu95m.png))

Comment: I did that in a photo editor for brevity in the question here. I cropped the image to reduce the length here

Comment: When you mess with the CSS/JS of a page, it's totally expected that elements will go missing. There is no bug. If you want to see a site as the site developers meant you to see it, don't use userscripts, browser extensions, etc.

Comment: Related?: [Why doesn't this question have any linked questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294605/1017231)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard, thank you for the response, but I believe that we learn by meddling with something that inspires us. And i'm the owner of the plugin so I know for sure that the plugin is not the cause. Although I understand your concern & the risks of using userscripts or browser extensions, I don't think that should stop you from using them. A lot of them are meant to make your life easier and my plugin is open source as well, so any risk it poses will be visible there in the code base. The intent behind the question was to seek help and share it for anyone who has same question.

Comment: The Linked list is visible now. So I'm guessing it just take time, although I couldn't find anywhere what's the reason or how long it takes.