# The link is gone, but the linked question still appears

Tags: bug, linked-questions

Consider [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225949/lim-x-to-0-frac-pi-x-logx-pi-x2x2-12-should-not-be-defined). On the right column, there is a “**Linked**” section which contains a single question. However, there is no link from the first question to the second one. There was once, in a comment, but that comment was deleted. In my opinion, it makes no sense that the second question is still considered as being linked to the first one.

Comment: Yeah, the linked list doesn't get sanitized. I think that is by-design. They don't track which event led to the addition of the link to the postlinks table so they have no way to remove it if an compensating event is posted. And you need some counter, and re-parse all posts. This will be a no-fix for sure.

Comment: Interestingly, somewhat similar bug report from 2013 is marked (status-completed): [Questions not removed from “Linked” when comments are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75046).