# Are questions with the same title and same URL acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Two questions have identical titles:

> Regex expression using word boundary for matching alphanumeric and non
>   alphanumeric characters in javascript

The URL's are also identical:
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215468/regex-expression-using-word-boundary-for-matching-alphanumeric-and-non-alphanume`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215468/regex-expression-using-word-boundary-for-matching-alphanumeric-and-non-alphanume) and
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214204/regex-expression-using-word-boundary-for-matching-alphanumeric-and-non-alphanume`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214204/regex-expression-using-word-boundary-for-matching-alphanumeric-and-non-alphanume)
Well, not quite! They have different numeric identifiers, at least I assume that is the purpose of the number in the URL. Note also that the question content in both is similar in meaning, although not identically worded. Why isn't this a bug?
**EDIT #1**
I just noticed that the questions were merged. However they both were displayed in a list of similar questions, one beneath the other, on a recent regex question (sorry, I should have taken a screen shot).

If questions have been merged, should they still display separately in the related question column?

**EDIT #2**
Sorry it took so long. And kind of fuzzy! 
[image: an example of merged files still appearing]

Comment: This is when you flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: "not quite identical" == different, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the system prevents duplicated titles now... It probably wouldn't let you finish editing them (if you tried) without changing the title to something unique.

Comment: Yes, merged questions could possibly be displayed in a list of questions as two separate questions.

Comment: @animuson yes, duplicate titles are expressly forbidden now on any given SE site. One of those 'we should have thought of this 2 years ago' ideas..

Comment: As for your question in EDIT #2: the linked list is cached and [only rebuilt when a question is edited, or every 30 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47898/broken-link-in-linked-posts-section/79318#79318). (As an aside: please, *one* question per question in future posts, and don't be afraid to *edit* posts rather than just adding stuff!)