# Do closed migrated questions always redirect now?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, migration, redirection

I've noticed today that migrated questions now redirect immediately to the target site. Previously, I had enough rep that the original question was still visible on the original site without an automatic redirect. Has this changed?

Comment: For the record, I preferred the old way.  It took me quite a while to figure out how I got from serverfault.com to superuser.com when clicking on this question:  http://serverfault.com/questions/217468/how-do-i-select-all-text-in-vi-vim-closed

Comment: @Matt, I didn't understand your confusion... until I read your link text.  That is a bit startling if you expected to go to server fault.

Comment: @@JJnguy exactly :-).

Comment: Merged questions now redirect also, it seems.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52745/154388) have anything to do with it?

Comment: I think Jeff and Jarrod changed this yesterday ... people were confused about where questions were going ... the idea was to simplify

Comment: I think it's far less confusing when the site actually *tells* you where it's about to send you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design -- we feel a migrated question should take you directly to the destination, since otherwise it's just another click to get to the actual question and any answers.

You can avoid this automatic redirect if you need to by adding `?noredirect=true` or `?noredirect=1` to the end of the question URL.

Comment: Ok. You did originally say you might [broaden that in the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mov/52585#52585). The future is now!

Comment: Are the original questions also all getting automatically deleted? It seems that way, which makes the `?noredirect=1` link rather useless for <10K users. What is the rationale for this? If I vote to close/migrate a question, I should be able to see what happened to it, not have it completely disappear.

Comment: This might make sense when you're coming from a search engine, but if you're just browsing through the site, IMO it's really weird.  For example, I'm in serverfault.com, and I click on a question that has been migrated.  The sites do not look *that* different, so unless I'm looking closely, I am fooled into thinking my reputation score has changed (yikes!), the search engine gives me different results, etc.  Furthermore, if I see the original question first, with a note that it's been migrated, I learn something about what types of questions are appropriate for SF vs. SU.

Comment: Maybe a good compromise is to do the re-direct, but then have a banner appear at the top of the page notifying me that I've been re-directed (similar to what's displayed when SE automatically logs me in).

Comment: @matt that's a really good idea, let me look into that

Comment: @TylerH You just added the content of another answer below into this one, reducing the value of  that answer completely. If anything, the edit is better in that answer as it wouldn't conflict with author's intent there.

Comment: @TheMaster The other answer, while mentioning the existence of the parameter, is otherwise today invalid due to later system changes. [Since 2014](/q/208904/377214), the link on the destination site was changed to link to the revision history (with no parameters) instead of to the question with that parameter. Also, [in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339794/377214), the notice containing the link was changed to be hidden after 60 days.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The essence of this edit is the query parameter. The essence of the other answer is the query parameter - not that there's a link(which there still is - in the timeline). Even if it was about the link, Wouldn't you agree that the edit that this info adds, would be a better fit in that answer? Better - as it flows with the original author's intent, which is to **provide a alternate way to access the link**, which Jeff never attempts to do in this answer.

Comment: @TheMaster First, there's no issue with multiple answers containing the same information. Second, this is the accepted answer, so it's better for it to contain all the useful information possible. Finally, I added not just the information that the other answer included, I _also_ added another way, and provided a different way to access it than what the other answer said. And, as Sonic mentioned above, the method the other user provided is actually incorrect/inaccurate today.

Answer (score 5):

There's a link on the destination site that sends you back to the closed version of question on the original site. It passes `?noredirect=1` querystring to force not to redirect.