# Stop direct links on migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, migration, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Roll back the new auto-redirect on migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73734/roll-back-the-new-auto-redirect-on-migrated-questions)

I just had it happen to me that I clicked on a closed question on Super User and it immediately directed me to Stack Overflow, where it had been migrated.  So I have no idea who did the migration, and if there had been edit history, I'm not sure it would have all gone over.  If **ALL** of the information isn't moved with the question, then please don't make the link take me directly to the other site.

Another point is that since I don't know up front if the question was migrated, I won't know whether to right-click on it to open it in another tab, as opposed to opening it in the same window.  I want to keep my Super User window on Super User.

**Edit:**  Now it's getting ridiculous.  I clicked on a link to an SO question and got a "page not found" page on Webmasters.  SE is going to end up being a graveyard of dead links.

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of [Roll back the new auto redirect on migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73734/roll-back-the-new-auto-redirect-on-migrated-questions).

Comment: @Grace, yep, voted to close as dupe.

Comment: why close as dupe, when one can delete?

Comment: @abel, Because the wording being different will help prevent future dupes, and it will draw attention to the original question.