# When the migration stub is deleted, redirection doesn't occur

Tags: bug, migration, deleted-questions, ios-app

I was reading [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299862/what-to-do-with-a-question-thats-been-asked-in-order-to-create-a-tag-for-a-new) on Meta Stack Overflow my iPhone, and, when I clicked the link to [the question they were talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558510/id-like-to-introduce-new-tag-ko-and-make-it-a-synonym-for-knockout-js), I got an error "question not found".

However, I noticed that I was not able to reproduce the problem on the regular website; further research has discovered that [this has definitely been done back in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mo); it is clear that this is a mobile only problem.

I suspect it is related to the fact that we [cannot view deleted posts via the api](https://stackapps.com/questions/1917/provide-a-way-to-retrieve-questions-and-answers-that-have-been-deleted#), but it would be nice if there were some sort of workaround.

I am using Beta version 1.3.2.216.